# Oracle DB Table Size By per year record count

Tags: sql, oracle

I can get total DB table size by using below command:

```
EXEC SQL.

   SELECT SUM(BYTES) / 1024 FROM DBA_SEGMENTS WHERE OWNER = :dbown AND
                                             SEGMENT_TYPE = 'TABLE' AND
                                             SEGMENT_NAME = :TABNAME
                                             INTO :TABSIZE

ENDEXEC
```

.

But I want to calculate DB table size by per year record count. How can I achieve this

Regards,

Pradip

Comment: What does "by per year record count" mean?  Does your table have a `date` column that indicates what year you want to include it in?  How accurate do you need the result to be?  How do you want to allocate overhead?  Can you, for example, assume that the average row size is equal for each year's data?

Comment: Table has date column based on which I can have record count per year.

Comment: OK.  What about the other questions?  Can you assume that the size of a row is constant over time?  How do you want to allocate overhead?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest trick I can think of is to create an empty duplicate table, insert one row, retrieve the bytes for the single row.Since your rows have specified lengths independent of the content you enter the byte size of each row should be the same for everything.

Then all you have to do is to get an idea of how many rows per year are inserted into the table. This you would typically do by using a e.g.

```
SELECT to_char(a.insert_date, 'yyyy')      YEAR, 
       sum(to_char(a.insert_date, 'yyyy')) ENTRIES
FROM   yourTable a 
GROUP BY to_char(a.insert_date, 'yyyy')
```

.

Or am I getting your question wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact science this. Consider that over the years the table might have had columns added/modified. So, given that caveat, the way I would do what you want quickly is to query dba_Segment as you have done to get the total size, then write a query on the table to return row count by year, and then split the total size by the yearly rowcounts in proportion.